# Firebase Android: Permission denied

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Recién estoy aprendiendo a usar Firebase, pero mi mayor obstáculo es que la documentación que encuentro es antigua y los otros post donde se soluciona este problema es con versiones anteriores de firebase.

Estoy intentando ingresar datos en la BBDD desde una aplicación hecha en Android Studio usando la estructura de este ejemplo:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start?hl=es-419

En mi caso, mi entrada es algo tal que así:

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}
public void RealizarEntrada(View v){
  //Bloque de código grande
  DatabaseReference mref = database.getReference("usuarios/usuario/comidas/fecha/hora");
    mref.child("plato1").setValue(datos[0]);
    mref.child("plato2").setValue(datos[1]);
    mref.child("postre").setValue(datos[2]);
}
```

De forma resumida, los datos de "usuario", "fecha", "hora" y la array se definen a lo largo del bloque de código anterior. Y al ejecutarlo, la consola me escupe este error:

```
2019-05-18 18:12:05.337 8180-8574/cardenas.marc.gestioncomidas D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-05-18 18:12:06.971 8180-8573/cardenas.marc.gestioncomidas W/RepoOperation: setValue at /usuarios/test/comidas/2019418/6125/plato1 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2019-05-18 18:12:07.029 8180-8573/cardenas.marc.gestioncomidas W/RepoOperation: setValue at /usuarios/test/comidas/2019418/6125/plato2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2019-05-18 18:12:07.034 8180-8573/cardenas.marc.gestioncomidas W/RepoOperation: setValue at /usuarios/test/comidas/2019418/6125/postre failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

En otros post, dicen que se debe a que los permisos de Firebase en esa DDBB no son públicos, sin embargo, cuando voy a la consola de firebase me sale este mensaje:
"Tus reglas de seguridad están definidas como públicas, así que cualquiera puede robar, modificar o eliminar datos de tu base de datos."
Y el Json de las reglas es bastante diferente al que se usaba hace dos meses, me sale tal que así:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?
Como punto final, comento que también he usado FirebaseAuth en ese mismo proyecto con esa misma DDBB y ese si me funciona, así que están conectados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a los nodos hijos de Firebase utiliza el método child().

prueba con:

```
private DatabaseReference dataRef;

dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuarios").child("usuario").child("comidas").child("fecha").child("hora");
```

Mira los permisos de Firebase Database en lugar de firestore.

```
 {
 security rules. 
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Para otro tipo de permisos : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: Al final, tal como digiste, resultó que mi problema era tan absurdo como que estaba intentàndolo con una BBDD de tipo "Cloud Firestore" pero con el código de una "Realtime Database", no sabía que existían dos tipos XD
Gracias por la ayuda ^-^/